# issues using leiden in R reticulate

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, reticulate

I'm trying to use the leiden algorithm in R, I would like to use it in a shiny app.
But I can't even get it to work in Rstudio console.

When I use reticulate (v 1.26) as is, i can't set a python path or conda environment. I get following error:

```
Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument
```

When I use reticulate (also v 1.26) in renv (v 0.16), at least I can set a python path and run python code,
but as soon as I'm using code that uses the leidenalg internally I get this error, although it is installed in the conda environment it is using:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ImportError: Please install the leiden algorithm: `conda install -c conda-forge leidenalg` or `pip3 install leidenalg`.
```

If I specifically try to import the module with import leidenalg, the error is different:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _c_leiden: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried using the R package leiden , I have tried importing python modules and using it in R , I've tried sourcing a file with python functions.
I have also tried more than once to create a new conda environment hoping it would fix the DLL problem.
when I try to import leidenalg in a python-consule (in the conda environment) I can load it without issues

What do I need to sacrifice to the R-gods to be able to use the leiden algorithm?

Comment: Does `leidenalg` use `pytables` as a dependency?

Comment: @JuanC no, I just checked the documentation to be sure

Comment: [here's someone with an issue very similar to yours](https://github.com/scverse/scanpy/issues/2108), it might help (also mentions leiden algorithm)

Comment: fixed by using different reticulate version: devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate", ref = "86ebb56")